# Showing error even after deleting the file: Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'am getting this eror upon running

```
php artisan tail
```

> [2018-01-02 05:51:27] local.ERROR: date() expects at least 1
>   parameter, 0 given {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0):
>   date() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given at
>   /var/www/html/laravel55api/database/factories/PostFactory.php:11)

even after deleting the file containing this error.

I tried clearing cache and config using artisan command.

But none solved the issue.

Comment: Laravel 4 added an Artisan command to tail the laravel.log file on a remote connection. This feature was removed from Laravel 5 and i think you are using Laravel 5.5!!

Comment: If you still want to use it do: `composer require spatie/laravel-tail`
You're done. Run `php artisan tail` to tail your log.

Comment: already installed and that's why i can see this error

Comment: Then the error is in `PostFactory.php` file! See that at line 11. You can show us here that file!

Comment: The file is no more existing...

Answer (score 0):

In the log file i have checked the time.

> [2018-01-02 09:05:41] local.INFO: Listing products   [2018-01-02
>   09:06:22] local.INFO: Listing products   [2018-01-02 09:10:38]
>   local.INFO: Listing products

It's justing showing the previous errors in the log.That's all.Something else is blocking my view in browser.

In laravel 5.5. version, they are keeping daily log.

cd storage/logs then run

> tail -f laravel.log

will shows the last log